# Creating a function so I dont have to repeat the statement 'document.querySelector()'

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a function so that when you pass in an argument inside of the parameter (the class name for a specific html tag), it will display this:

```
document.querySelector(className)

//where the parameter className is the class name of a specific html tag/element i want to manipulate.
```

Furthermore, I want the value returned by the function (code above), to be functional like do a (.textContent = ' ') or (style.backgroundColor = 'red')

I have tried to do a function for it and it works fine as it displays the result I want it to. However, the problem comes when i try to do a (.style.backgroundColor = 'red';) or (.textContent = 'Hello').

```
// the values passed into the parameter are the class names for a specific html tag. 
const docs = (className) => `document.querySelector('.${className}')`

// the argument 'title' in the 'docs' funciton is the class name for my h1 tag
const title = docs('title')


console.log(title)

title.textContent = 'Hello!';
title.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```

Comment: You are creating a string.... You should have the string literal inside of the querySelector parenthesis, not around the entire thing.

Comment: _“I have tried to do a function for it and it works fine as it displays the result I want it to”_ — Your function returns a string. [`document.querySelector`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) returns an [`Element`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element) or `null`.

Answer (score 3):

Your `docs()` function is returning a string, not an Element object. The template literal should only be used within the argument you provide to `querySelector()`:

```js
const docs = (className) => document.querySelector(`.${className}`);
const title = docs('title')

title.textContent = 'Hello!';
title.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```

```html
<div class="title"></div>
```

It's worth noting however, that this is a rather odd design choice for a couple of reasons. Firstly, it limits you to only making class selectors. Secondly it limits you to only being able to select nodes from the `document` directly, instead of from any Element object.

If the only requirement here is brevity, then it's not a worthwhile enough goal given the limitations you're imposing on yourself. I'd suggest the more common pattern of declaring variables with meaningful (and concise) names, containing the required Elements from the DOM at the start of a block and re-using them.

Comment: That should do the trick!!!!